# How do I use multprocessing.Value (or other shared resources) on Mac with Spawn?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, shared-memory

Example:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

counter = mp.Value('i', 0)

def test_fun(i):
    global counter
    with counter.get_lock():
        counter.value += 1

def main():
    global counter
    with mp.Pool(4) as p:
        result = p.map(test_fun, range(4))
    print(counter.value)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The expected output is 4, since the value is shared but outputs 0 on Mac.

It works when using linux or using `fork` but I'd like it work with Spawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just move counter declaration to your main function, then set it as a global variable inside the children initializer, same way it's done on windows.

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

def setup_fn(value):
    global counter
    counter = value

def test_fun(i):
    global counter
    with counter.get_lock():
        counter.value += 1

def main():
    counter = mp.Value('i', 0)
    with mp.Pool(4, initializer=setup_fn, initargs=(counter,)) as p:
        result = p.map(test_fun, range(4))
    print(counter.value)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: @thc , the way multiprocessing works is that it will call X interpreters, and have them execute this file , but with a different `__name__`, obviously different interpreters will have their versions of `counter` if it is originally in the global scope, now i want to create only 1 counter, so i create it in the main process, but it also needs to exist in the global scope of all the children ... so i have each child run the initializer to modify its global namespace on startup, in other words the child is a new interpreter that only executes the initializer and your second function, nothing else